# "Parsing error. failed: Data source does not exist." is thrown when running a maven project in InteliJ

Tags: java, maven, robotframework

Im trying to run a so simple and first maven project in InteliJ, using robot plugin for maven and when I try to run that project(using "robotframework:run" in the command lines in the edit configuration options in the IDE or just adding "run" in the dependencies in the POM file, I get that error:

[ ERROR ] Parsing '' failed: Data source does not exist.

If I remove this goal, that error is not thrown but the test does not run.

Im so new in that, so maybe Im running maven project in a wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to attach something more specifict

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that you told robot to run a file, but it can't find the file. The filename it thinks you told it to run is between the quotes. In this case it looks like an empty string.

Comment: I did not set the path in the question, but it looked like the path did not like and when I removed the goal, the error was not more shown but anyway the project was not run. Therefore I think it is run in a wrong way. Because I have checked the path using ls in the command lines and it exist

Comment: @nany: it will help if you edit your question to show the exact command line being run.